# Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" Vue - Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel & Vue together, when i try to output this slider images from AXIOS, i get this error and the slider plugin functionalities do not work (like clicking on an thumbnail does not change the image, and the website has shopping cart, it does not even open it etc)

Template:

```
            <agile
              class="main"
              ref="main"
              :options="options1"
              :as-nav-for="asNavFor1"
            >
              <div
                class="slide"
                v-for="(slide, index) in JSON.parse(product.images)"
                :key="index"
                :class="`slide--${index}`"
              >
                <img class="agile-img" :src="'/storage/product/' + slide" />
              </div>
            </agile>
            <agile
              class="thumbnails"
              ref="thumbnails"
              :options="options2"
              :as-nav-for="asNavFor2"
            >
              <div
                class="slide slide--thumbniail"
                v-for="(slide, index) in JSON.parse(product.images)"
                :key="index"
                :class="`slide--${index}`"
                @click="$refs.thumbnails.goTo(index)"
              >
                <img class="agile-img" :src="'/storage/product/' + slide" />
              </div>
              <template slot="prevButton">
                <i class="fas fa chevron-left"></i>
              </template>
              <template slot="nextButton">
                <i class="fas fa chevron-right"></i>
              </template>
            </agile>
```

Script:

```
 axios
      .get("/api/product-detail/" + this.product_id)
      .then((response) => {
        this.product = response.data;
        console.log(JSON.parse(this.product.images));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

The output of the console log is console.log(JSON.parse(this.product.images));

```
(2) ["products1041473366.png", "products426786637.jpg"]
```

[image: Error Console]

[image: Output, when you click on thumbnails ntng happens]

Comment: Is that axios call being made in a Watcher? Based on the errors logged, it looks like the `JSON.parse()` call that's throwing the error is coming from inside a watcher. (Just a hunch, I could be interpreting incorrectly)

Comment: axios inside a mounted()   axios
      .get("/api/product-detail/" + this.product_id)
      .then((response) => {
        this.product = response.data;
      })